# flyspell no longer working on emacs28

Tags: flyspell

Whenever I enable `flyspell-mode` on any file, I immediately get the below error:

```
Error in post-command-hook (flyspell-post-command-hook): (wrong-type-argument keymapp nil)
```

And after that flyspell stops working. Has anyone else encountered this issue? I was able to reproduce the error on `emacs -Q`. If I enable `toggle-debug-on-error`, I'm not getting any backtraces.

emacs version:

```
Emacs version: GNU Emacs 28.0.50 (build 1, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.24.22, cairo version 1.17.3)
 of 2020-08-18, built using commit fc9b68636b1aec69295726d2b3be2b520911f40b.

./configure options:
  --with-modules --with-rsvg --with-dbus --with-imagemagick --without-pop --with-xft --with-xml2 --with-libotf --with-mailutils --without-toolkit-scroll-bars --without-xaw3d -with-nativecomp 'CFLAGS=-O3 -mtune=native -march=native -fomit-frame-pointer'

Features:
  XPM JPEG TIFF GIF PNG RSVG CAIRO IMAGEMAGICK SOUND GPM DBUS GSETTINGS GLIB NOTIFY INOTIFY ACL GNUTLS LIBXML2 FREETYPE HARFBUZZ LIBOTF ZLIB GTK3 X11 XDBE XIM MODULES NATIVE_COMP THREADS LIBSYSTEMD JSON PDUMPER LCMS2
```

Here is my emacs config: https://github.com/CSRaghunandan/.emacs.d/blob/master/setup-files/setup-spell.el.

I tried with both `hunspell` and `aspell` and both are giving the same error.

If I enable flyspell-lazy-mode and enabe `toggle-debug-on-error`, I get the below error backtrace:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument keymapp nil)
  make-flyspell-overlay(1313 1317 flyspell-duplicate highlight)
  flyspell-highlight-incorrect-region(1313 1317 doublon)
  flyspell-word()
  flyspell-check-region-doublons(1289 1350)
  flyspell-large-region(1289 1350)
  flyspell-region(1289 1350)
  apply(flyspell-region (1289 1350))
  flyspell-lazy-check-pending()
  apply(flyspell-lazy-check-pending nil)
  timer-event-handler([t 0 1 0 t flyspell-lazy-check-pending nil idle 0])
```

Answer (score 1):

So, I found out what the mistake was after an hour of debugging.

I had the line `(setq flyspell-mouse-map nil)` to disable the mouse map for flyspell and this was causing `flyspell` to stop working on emacs.

After removing the above line, flyspell is working fine without any issues.

Comment: That's a keymap -- `nil` isn't a valid value.  Try `(setq flyspell-mouse-map (make-sparse-keymap))`